# How to install user Applescripts for Safari and activate the Scripts menu item?

Tags: safari, applescript, menu-bar

I want to add a user script to Safari and activate the Script menu for Safari.

[image: Script Menu Item]

I have seen some references which indicate this can be done by adding a .scpt to `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Safari` but that does not seem to work. Neither does `~/Library/Application Scripts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to **Script Editor** > **Preferences**, then check "Show Script menu in menu bar" and "Show Computer Scripts". Afterwards, the Script Editor menu bar should show.

[image: Script Editor General Preferences]

[image: Script Editor Menu Bar]

Then, you go to "**Open Scripts Folder** -> **Open Safari Scripts Folder**", where the folder you specified will be added.

[image: Safari Scripts Folder]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the version of macOS or Safari you're running, but usually you would do this:

1. In the Finder, go to the top level of your Mac's hard drive (or SSD)
2. Navigate to /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/
3. Double-click on the **Script Menu.menu** file

This should add the Script Menu to a number of supported apps, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Mojave the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/` doesn't have a `Script Menu.menu` file...